# Express the given limit as a definite integral

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I'm supposed to convert this limit to a definite integral but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do it.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot\sqrt{ \frac i{n}} $$

Would appreciate some help/guidelines on how to tackle problems like this because I haven't found that many great sources to learn from when Googling it. My textbook is also really vague on this and doesn't really explain it or include examples.

Comment: What is $\Delta x$? Once you recognize that, what is $f(x_i^*)$? From this, you can determine what $f(x)$ is and the bounds for the integral.

Comment: It's the limit of Riemann sums for $\int_0^1f.$ What is $f$ in this case?

Comment: I would assume that $f(x) = \sqrt x $ here? And $ \Delta x $ is equal to $ \frac 1 {n} $ ?

Comment: For any $f\in C^0([0,1])$ we have that
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx. $$ In your case $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ gives that the limit equals $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio is the $f$ in the sum necessarily the same $f$ of the integral? To me it seems that only on $\mathbb{Q}$ they have to give the same picture. Since for example for no $k,n\in \mathbb{N}\quad f(k/n)=f(1/\sqrt{2}).$  I accept that the result is the same but the functions don't have to be the same, right?

Comment: @ty.: if two continuous functions agree on $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ they agree on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, I did not see that $f\in C^0([0,1])$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, this looks like a Riemann sum of some function where the partition consists of $n$ evenly spaced points between $0$ and $1$. That is, if $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, and $P=\{0,1/n,2/n,\ldots, n/n\}$, then a (uppeR) Riemann sum of this function over $P$ is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i+1}{n}-\frac{i}{n}\right)f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)=\sum_{I=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}.$$

Since $f$ is integrable on $0,1$, this converges to $\int_0^1 f$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Is there some "general things" that I should start looking for in problems like this to see what $ \Delta x $ etc is? This was a pretty easy question so I guess it won't be as simple for me going forward to more advanced stuff. Also, I don't really get how you get that $( \frac {i+1} {n} - \frac i {n}) f( \frac i {n}) $ is equal to the sigma notation in my post?